# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory In recursive Node js code

Tags: node.js

when i am writing recursive program which reads 70mb file line by 
line and processes.I am using recursion to process the line .here is my code

```
function readFile(response, postData){

    var instream = fs.createReadStream('filePath');
    var datmap={};
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: instream,
        output: outstream,
        terminal: false
    });

    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        hirarchyFun(datmap,line); 
    });
}

hirarchyFun=function(map,line){
    var key;
    if(line.indexOf(",") != -1){
        key=line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","));
        var subLine=line.substring((key.length+1));
        var internMap=map[key];
        if(typeof internMap == 'undefined'){
            internMap={};
        }
        var value=hirarchyFun(internMap,subLine);
        map[key]=value;
        return map;
    }else{
        return line;
    }
}
```

when I am reading file which is about 70mb giving error as

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

but its working fine for file about 700kb.
can any one help on this issue??

Comment: why dont you try to add a callback on hirachyFun function and use it in asynchronously .

Comment: I am getting the same when I was trying primes below 1 Bn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)