# npm publish Fails with "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory"

Tags: node.js, npm

When I want to publish my node module, which can be seen at [github](https://github.com/Templum/node-api-mocker). I keep receiving the following error message.

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

In my early publishes I never encountered this problem. Also I yet dont know how to get a proper log or any form of information which may help me solving this problem.

Iam using `Node.js 0.12.2` on Windows 10. And Code was written using the latest visual studio.

Thanks for all suggestion in advance

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but have you looked at other similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory for example.

Comment: @bali182 I saw that post. But its more a problem which encounters during runtime. When I use my module (for example npm test) I never encountert this problem. I only get it when I do $npm publish pathToFolder