# FATAL ERROR - When Running Protractor + CucumberJs + Grunt + NPM

Tags: node.js, selenium, gruntjs, protractor, selenium-grid

I'm struggling with the following issue.

I had created some e2e tests, which they passes successfully when I run them locally, with locally I mean, when I run tests by starting the application up, using an NPM script thats uses the grunt task like this:

*package.json:*

> "e2e-local": "scripts/test-e2e.sh local"

*test-e2e.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

grunt test:e2e:"$1" --tags "$2"
```

But when I run my test using BrowserStack's selenium server or my own... I'm getting:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

 1221269 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.9 (1435.0) -> 1372.8 (1435.0) MB, 675.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
 1222093 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.8 (1435.0) -> 1372.8 (1435.0) MB, 722.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
 1222832 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.8 (1435.0) -> 1372.8 (1435.0) MB, 738.8 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
 1223560 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.8 (1435.0) -> 1372.8 (1435.0) MB, 727.9 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x2903647c9fa9 <JS Object>
    2: encode64s [/Users/brunosoko/OLAPIC/LemuramaModsquad/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/formatter/json_formatter.js:~126] [pc=0x25cdf0f7939] (this=0x2903647e99d9 <JS Global Object>,input=0x24ffe942e499 <Very long string[5816704]>)
    3: embedding [/Users/brunosoko/OLAPIC/LemuramaModsquad/node_modules/gherkin/lib/gherkin/formatter/json_formatter.js:58] [pc=0x25cdedec016] (this=0x10ab271a84f...

FATALAbort trap: 6
```

I would appreciate any though about this! I had tried what states in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35650414/4226971) as well but nothing!