# Gulp - CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, gulp

When calling one of my gulp task, I get "`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory`".

I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory) that I can pass a parameter to node to increase the default memory limit : `node --max-old-space-size=2000  server.js`. But how can I tell gulp to pass a parameter to node.exe ? Here is [the list of flags](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli#flags) I can pass to gulp, I was hoping to find one that gulp passes to node when it launches it for a task.

The task causing the issue :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  var OUTPUT_FOLDER = '../Release_Prepared/';
  var extensionsToOptimize = ['gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'svg'];
  var glob = [];

  for(var i=0; extensionsToOptimize.length; i++){
    glob.push(OUTPUT_FOLDER + '**/*.' + extensionsToOptimize[i]);
  }

  gulp.src(glob)
  .pipe(imagemin({
    verbose: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(OUTPUT_FOLDER));
});
```

Comment: If your on windows you need to do a bit differently using set, e.g " SET variable=string"

so you would do "set max-old-space-size=2000"

and then node.exe server.js

but you might want to solve your memory issue instead of just increasing the memory....

Comment: Windows has no issues with `node --max-old-space-size=2000  server.js`, it understands `programName --parameter` just fine. My question is how do I pass node parameters from a gulp task ?

Comment: Those Arguments get sent directly to V8 (engine behind Node), you don't need to pass it as an argument to a gulp task...  There are plenty of good docs on setting those commands.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I just found out today that gulp can be given any V8 option and it will be passed to node.  For example, do `gulp yourTask --max_old_space_size=2000` and it will give you the results you want.  To see a list of V8 flags to pass, type `node --v8-options` in your terminal.

Comment: You have made my day!

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 6):

In our case First time it was Fine when i was executing gulp build command. I have Four separate tasks. Each task creates separate built files for each modules. we have been running Gulp command for the final build.

There we faced the `process out of memory` issue continuously. Even though if we allocate large memory to the process. Like below - around 8GB. But, still it was failing.

```
gulp --max-old-space-size=8192
```

**Solution:**

> 1. Just delete the previous built files which is created already. And the
>      above command creates the new file. So the process works seamlessly.

For example:
Delete `main-built.js` Manually / Through automation commands.

> 2. In other case just clear the cache by executing the below command.

`npm cache clean`

> 3. Since we had large amount of JS files. that is also another case,
>      it could cause this kind of problems. Remove unwanted and unused Js
>      files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We are using azure build pipelines. Should the `npm cache clean` be used before gulp build or after gulp build? @rajeshkdev

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should run this kind of command when you start the bash script build

```
node --max-old-space-size=2000 ./node_modules/.bin/gulp {your gulp script e.g gulb.js}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by manually deleting my built js/css (dest) files, then re-running the gulp task. This goes along with RJK's answer above, but did not have to allocate new memory.

Answer (score 0):

Search for gulp.cmd and modify that file like this:

@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js --max-old-space-size=1400" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js --max-old-space-size=1400" %*
)

Answer (score 0):

Give more memory not solved to me. What happen:

I lost some days with this problem, until I found that in some file I was importing a class from one static file, a builded file. It make the build process to never end. Something like:

```
import PropTypes from "../static/build/prop-types";
```

Fixing to the real source solved all the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simple project that ended up using gulp-imagemin, and had the same issue. The root issue was having LARGE marketing images and Gulp/Node just ran out of memory.

I could of course perform the accepted answer here. But these 4,000+ by 3,000+ pixel images had no business going up on the web anyways, and this error really just reminded me I missed re-sizing some of my images.

So if you get a similar error, check that you have appropriate sized images as gulp/node shouldn't choke on most normal sized builds.