# Set --max_old_space_size in gulp task in yaml

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, yaml, gulp

I have gulpfile.js in React App.

In Azure Pipeline , I have 3 tasks

- install node version
- install npm
- run gulp

```
      displayName: Run gulp
      inputs:
        gulpFile: ${{parameters.gulpFilePath}}
        targets: 
        arguments: 'production'
        gulpjs: 'node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'
        enableCodeCoverage: false
```

**But here I am getting below error**
[image: Javascript heap out of memory error]

[I followed from stackoverflow as well](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381749/1699320)

But not able to understand where I have to add this line of code in my gulp task
**--max_old_space_size=4096**

I tried to add few different way but its always fail.
I also passed in script liked below

```
task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Run npm install
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd ${{parameters.reactAppPath}}
      npm install
      gulp --max_old_space_size=4096  --gulpfile ${{parameters.gulpFilePath}} production
```

Then getting below error
[image]

Please help me
Thank you for all your help

Comment: I able to run pipeline -  task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Run Gulp'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd ${{parameters.reactAppPath}}
      node --max_old_space_size=4096 './node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js' --gulpfile ${{parameters.gulpFilePath}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No gulp file found error occurs when your Pipeline is not able to find the gulpfile.js in your repository.

**My Reactapp repository with gulpfile.js:-**

[image]

**My Azure yaml code to install and run gulp:-**

I have added the file path to my gulpfile.js and react app in variable and then referenced it later in Run gulp task like below:-

```yaml
variables:
  gulpFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/gulpfile.js'
  reactAppPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
.
.
.
.. cd $(reactAppPath)
   node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile $(gulpFilePath)
```

**Complete yaml code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- '*'

pr:
- '*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  gulpFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/gulpfile.js'
  reactAppPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

steps:
- task: UseNode@1
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  inputs:
    version: '18.x'

- script: npm install -g npm@latest
  displayName: 'Upgrade npm'

- script: npm install -g timers-promises
  displayName: 'Upgrade npm'

- script: npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-babel gulp-browserify gulp-plumber gulp-sourcemaps babelify vinyl-source-stream
  displayName: 'Upgrade npm'

# - script: npm install --global gulp
#   displayName: 'Install Gulp globally'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Run npm install'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd $(reactAppPath)
      npm install

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Run Gulp'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd $(reactAppPath)
      node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile $(gulpFilePath)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: you made my day