# Node.js Process out of memory in Cron job

Tags: node.js, express, cron

Hello I am facing an error while executing the code. Node process become out of memory. I am sharing my code via [github gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4569190cee3f547cc9bc8fae55356fae)
 I think there is some logical error. Please help me in resolving this error.

Here is my [app.js](https://gist.github.com/NomanMaqsood/dc33d2b15091167d597347cd2fb2acfd)

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)?

Comment: Yes I checked this. It does not work for me