# npm install - javascript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When running `npm install -g ionic` I get the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Is there a way to globally increase the node.js memory limit?

Comment: Can you tell us what OS are you using and what version node and npm is?

Comment: Windows 10, Node v6.8.1, npm v3.10.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can launch NPM using :

`node --max-old-space-size=8000 $(which npm) install -g ionic`

As described [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238), the default is 4000 (4Gb).

Comment: You can also launch :

`node --max_old_space_size=8000 $(which npm) install -g ionic`

Comment: The default V8 memory limit is 1.7 GB.

Comment: use the option `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` - Documentation : https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

Comment: Just want to point out that in my case, I got a `JavaScript heap out of memory` error because my machine didn't have enough memory. In this case, I had to *decrease* `max_old_space_size`, not increase it.

Comment: Anyone knows the Windows equivalent for this command? I'm trying to do `npm i` but getting this "out of memory" error.

Answer (score 23):

I flagged this as a duplicate, but in case anyone happens across it, I posted the modern solution to this problem over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48895989/4200039:

> As of v8.0 shipped August 2017, the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable exposes this configuration (see NODE_OPTIONS has landed in 8.x!). Per the article, only options whitelisted in the source are permitted, which includes "--max_old_space_size".
>
> So I put in my .bashrc:
> export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

Comment: I am trying to "npm publish" a .tgz with 650 MB size (unpacked 1.4 GB) and I get this issue. NODE_OPTIONS takes effect, but I get another error message ENOBUFS at the end.

Answer (score 14):

Run these commands

**npm install -g increase-memory-limit**

Run from the root location of your project:

**increase-memory-limit**

Look Here For more details https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Comment: I tried this solution, but now "npm run dev" AND "npm install" hangs for ever! any tips to solve this?

Comment: **deprecaded** As of Node.js v8.0 shipped August 2017, you can now use the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable to set the max_old_space_size globally:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Answer (score 11):

Try, `node --max-old-space-size=<size>` where size is in megabytes.

Comment: How do you set a node option when running npm install

Comment: @Jayraj launch npm through node

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar issue and this approach didn't work for me because I was using docker so I had to increase the memory size for docker itself to fix the issue:

[Docker Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2fIz.png)

Comment: For people having this issue on their docker build, this is the solution. upvote!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a recursive function which I didn't observe.Recursion can make heap out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using WSL-Ubuntu 2.

Simply move in Windows to C:/Users/Max and create a file called .wslconfig with this input:

```
[wsl2]
memory=16GB
```

(adjust if you want less memory)

This worked for me. "Max" is just a example for the current User

Answer (score -2):

For **Angular 11 / 10** in pacakge.json file make below changes

**Source [Link](https://thecodemon.com/resolved-fatal-error-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-during-angular-ng-serve/)**

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=2192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=2192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
   .....
```

},

[image]

Comment: These only show how to run ng commands, not npm install.

Answer (score -4):

Solved for me, after running the command:

```
npm update
```

It will update all dependencies (be careful with broken changes). Maybe the `webpack-cli` dependency is the cause of this trouble.

Answer (score -4):

Try this lifehack

`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=2048" npm install -g ionic`

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including the accepted answer.

Comment: Would actually argue that this is different, since its not calling node directly, but using the `NODE_OPTIONS` env variable. This allows you to prefix any command that runs node with it, without doing the `$(which <executable>)` thing

Answer (score -5):

I had an incorrect prefix in my .npmrc file. By moving to new company devices this path didn't match anymore with the old nodejs folder. On npm install the command freezes for a long time and throws an java out of heap exception without a suitable answer.

I've deleted it and it worked.

```
prefix=D:\development\nodejs
```