# Setting node parameters when running npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

This is a follow-up to [npm install Javascript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112279/npm-install-javascript-heap-out-of-memory). The answer recommends running node with `--max-old-space-size=<big_num>`

Is there a general way to pass this and other node options to the npm install command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM is just a node module, so you can do :

`node --max_old_space_size=<bignum> /usr/bin/npm`

Replace the paths by yours, obviously.