# FATAL ERROR: JavaScript heap out of memory when using any "npm" command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I'm getting error (FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory) when try to run any npm command. Error occurs even by running "npm -v".

have also gone through the thread-([npm install - javascript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112279/npm-install-javascript-heap-out-of-memory) ) but this didn't helped me out in my case.

Fetal error

```
    FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed 
    - 
    JavaScript heap out of memory
    1: 000000013F56F04A 
       v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+5114
    2: 000000013F54A0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
    3: 000000013F54AA30 node_module_register+2032
    4: 000000013F7D20EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
    5: 000000013F7D201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639


    6: 000000013FCF2BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556

     7: 000000013FCE9C46 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24310
     8: 000000013FCE829C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17740
     9: 000000013FCEE1B7 v8::internal::Heap::CreateFillerObjectAt+1175
    10: 000000013FB7C5B3 
    v8::internal::interpreter::Interpreter::GetDispatchCounters
    Object+78451
    11: 000000013F4D1132 
        v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+52082
    12: 000000013F4D17F3 
        v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+53811
    13: 000000013F5B1474 uv_dlerror+2436
    14: 000000013F5B21D8 uv_run+232

15: 000000013F55128E node::NewContext+1390
16: 000000013F55189B node::NewIsolate+603
17: 000000013F551D07 node::Start+839
18: 000000013F40935C node::MultiIsolatePlatform::MultiIsolatePlatform+604
19: 000000013FFAA93C 
   v8::internal::compiler::OperationTyper::ToBoolean+134796
20: 0000000076D3555D BaseThreadInitThunk+13
21: 0000000076F9385D RtlUserThreadStart+29

<--- Last few GCs --->

[13304:0000000000182610]   135335 ms: Mark-sweep 1396.6 (1426.7) -> 1396.6 (1424
.7) MB, 2368.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since start of marking, biggest st
ep 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2368 ms) (average mu = 0.099, current
 mu = 0.035) fi[13304:0000000000182610]   135404 ms: Scavenge 1397.6 (1424.7) ->
 1397.1 (1428.2) MB, 3.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.099, current mu = 0.035) allo
cation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - 
JavaS
cript heap out of memory
 1: 000000013FD7F04A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+5114
 2: 000000013FD5A0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 000000013FD5AA30 node_module_register+2032
 4: 000000013FFE20EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 000000013FFE201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 0000000140502BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556
 7: 00000001404F9C46 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24310
 8: 00000001404F829C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17740
 9: 00000001404FE1B7 v8::internal::Heap::CreateFillerObjectAt+1175
10: 000000014038C5B3 
    v8::internal::interpreter::Interpreter::GetDispatchCounters
    Object+78451
11: 000000013FCE1132 v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+52082
12: 000000013FCE17F3 v8::internal::StackGuard::ArchiveSpacePerThread+53811
13: 000000013FDC1474 uv_dlerror+2436
14: 000000013FDC21D8 uv_run+232
15: 000000013FD6128E node::NewContext+1390
16: 000000013FD6189B node::NewIsolate+603
17: 000000013FD61D07 node::Start+839
18: 000000013FC1935C node::MultiIsolatePlatform::MultiIsolatePlatform+604
19: 00000001407BA93C 
   v8::internal::compiler::OperationTyper::ToBoolean+134796
20: 0000000076D3555D BaseThreadInitThunk+13
21: 0000000076F9385D RtlUserThreadStart+29
```

Comment: **See Also**: [Node.js heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38558989/1366033)

Answer (score 10):

You need to raise the amount of memory allowed for node.

You can do that in a global scope by:

1. Open a `cmd` window
2. Run `setx NODE_OPTIONS --max_old_space_size=10240`
3. Close all cmd/code editors
4. Reopen cmd and run your node command again (npm, etc.)

Comment: This didn't work for me on Mac. `setx` command not found. FWIW.

Comment: This is not a solution, but a workaround. Before giving node 10GB! of RAM, it makes sense to understand why it needs that much. I came here to find steps on how to troubleshoot memory issues, but found this. Ehh...

Comment: In node.js you don't fix the things, just workaround the things ;)

Comment: @DavisJones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982005/where-do-i-set-node-options-max-old-space-size-2048 on macOS this worked for me `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"`

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue and it took ages to find out what was happening. If even `npm -v` fails on you then your problem is not caused by memory shortage but incorrect settings in `.npmrc` file. In my case I copied `.npmrc` from my old machine and I had `prefix` and `cache` settings redefined like that:

```
prefix=D:\npm-projects\npm
cache=D:\npm-projects\npm-cache
```

On my new machine I have only `C:\` drive thus `npm` was going crazy trying to process these settings. As soon as I changed everything to point to `C:\npm-projects\xxxx` problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and it took lots of time to find out what was happening..
so here is the solution what works for me

in Your package.json inside script just add the line
**"start": "craco --max_old_space_size=7096 start",**

Answer (score 0):

After Adding many Modules, while building the angular solution, I was getting
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

[image]

Solution:
In Package.json file where npm run command is mentioned, Add `&& node --max-old-space-size=10240`

or

close all other running applications which might use more memory like Visual Studio, SQL server management studio

Answer (score 0):

We realized that we had a 32-bit version of Node installed on our Windows machine. Installing a 64-bit version resolved it