# JavaScript heap out of memory while building GitLab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am building GitLab CI/CD pipeline using the docker nodejs image provided by my company. and also the gitlab group runner provided by my company.
When job runs `npm install` command we get the following error

`FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

or

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

quick [online search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982005/where-do-i-set-node-options-max-old-space-size-2048) suggest to increase the memory with NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

here is the pipeline job. I have tried different syntax with no luck

```
build-job:       
  image: "docker.mycomapy-images/nodejs:14"
  stage: build
  script:
    - node -v
    #- export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
    #- export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
    #- node --max-old-space-size=8192 `which npm` install
    - export NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192'
    - npm install
    - npm run build:prod
```

other option suggested was to set in [package.json](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238#issuecomment-367147962).
"scripts":
{
"start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 webpack"
}

none of the above options worked.

Can this be issue with runner itself? The runner I am using is AWS EC2 t3a.micro instance. I  believe the memory size on such instance is 1 GB. So I think NODE_OPTIONS will have no effect.

However, On the same runner, I was able to build if I change the image to official docker image `image: node:14` and in this case I do not even need to set NODE_OPTIONS

I am not sure if this is a runner issue or image issue

Error message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a image issue, since official nodejs docker image is name just "node", not "nodejs"