# azurepipe line hangs with react unit testing script jest and rtl

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, jestjs, azure-pipelines, react-testing-library

I have a react project based on [minimal theme](https://minimals.cc/)
RTL and jest are integrated into this project as well.

Locally running unit tests command is this

```
 "test:dev": "react-app-rewired test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!my-library-dir)/'",
```

This runs the unit tests and gives the expected results. So no issues in local environment.

This is my build pipeline script

```
- script: |
      npm install --global yarn
      yarn
      NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 npm run build
    displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

I changed it by adding unit tests line like this

```
 - script: |
      npm install --global yarn
      yarn
      npm run test:ci
      NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 npm run build
    displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

test:ci command is this

```
"test:ci": "CI=true react-app-rewired test --watchAll --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!my-library-dir)/'"
```

Now in the azure ci cd console, I see this

```
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        29.812 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Which means test cases run successfully. But now the problem is it doesn't trigger the next line in the pipeline which is

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 npm run build
```

The pipeline hangs for a long time and timeout.

How can I fix this with Azure DevOps and jest?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answers can give you some help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be related to the argument: `--watchAll`.

It will watch files for changes and rerun all tests when something changes. It may cause an infinite loop and never exit.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the `--watchAll` argument.

[image]

To solve the issue, you can remove the `--watchAll` flag or set the `--watchAll=false`.

In this case, the jest test will work as expected in Azure DevOps.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating it into three individual steps, which will have better output flow in the Azure DevOps UI, and allow for easier debugging if there is a problem with your syntax:

```
- script: |
    npm install --global yarn
    yarn
  displayName: 'Install yarn'

- script: |
    npm run test:ci
  displayName: 'Run tests'

- script: |
    NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 npm run build
  displayName: 'Run build'
```

All three steps will execute one after each other on the same agent (machine).

If this still does not work, I suspect there may be a problem with your command `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2048 npm run build` causing it not to be executed correctly. You can try changing it to `node --max_old_space_size=2048 npm run build` or setting `max_old_space_size` as an environment variable instead. If those options do not work, try searching on Stack Overflow or on your search engine. Here is an [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56982005/where-do-i-set-node-options-max-old-space-size-2048) that may help.