# Npm call_and_retry_last

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, centos

I've laravel app on my server when I try to run `npm run prod` I get this error

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

**any idea?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112279/npm-install-javascript-heap-out-of-memory

Comment: @user3532758 `Welcome to Node.js v12.18.3. Type ".help" for more information.`!

Comment: What haha I shared this link because I had the same issue and that answer helped me. I was running node on windows.