# How to lessen node.js heap memory usage (not increase heap amount)

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3, out-of-memory, heap-memory

We ran into an issue where our package started crashing when we built it due to `js heap out of memory`

We found info from [javascript-heap-out-of-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112279/npm-install-javascript-heap-out-of-memory) and [node-js-heap-out-of-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory) and found that we could increase the heap default, but we found no information about how to lessen the required amount to begin with.

**Our question is regarding lowering the heap usage to start:**

- Do we lessen the heap usage simply by removing dependencies that might not be necessary? *(this didn't work, we are already at bare minimum)*
- Could packages be pre-compressed beforehand somehow? *(is that even a thing?)*
- Do we combine packages into our own packages, taking only what we need from each one and redistributing them as a smaller version of those packages where possible depending on licensing rights, etc.? *(this seems very extreme and NOT something we'd actually try to do)*
- Or maybe there is a way the whole thing could be built in chunks and put together later so that it never has to use all the allocated heap at once?  *(This one sounds like a fun and possible project, but we have no idea where to even start)*
- Some other way that we are unaware of?

We didn't know where else to get such information, so we really appreciate the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"we could increase the heap default"* this should not be your first reaction. If you run out of heap memory look at the code: you probably have too many object references that are kept alive when they shouldn't: reduce the scope of variables to the minimum (certainly limit global variables, and avoid large collections that are global). Use weak references when no strong references are needed (like WeapMap instead of Map), ...etc.

Comment: Right, that's what we want to do, lessen the required amount, not increase the amount available.  I will look through the code and see where we can improve the object references to see if that helps, thanks!