# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory:-node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am querying the database and sending the response to the UI, res.json, when I query database for large data, I get

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

and `-max_old_space_size=2000000`
is working fine but I don't want to use it as the app will be used by many people in different system, Is there any other way I can solve it.
will streaming the JSON data help or any other way in which it can be done.

```
var onDataEvent = dataStream.on('data', function (row) {
            dataRows.push(row);
          });
var onDataEndEvent = dataStream.on('end', function () {
        dataBody.DATA = dataRows;
        res.json(repapiResponseBody);
      });
```

I am getting the database response stream  from the database and converting it to json object(because I might need to transform the response based not the request parameter) and sending the response.

Comment: _"will streaming the JSON data help"_. Possibly. Hard to tell without the code that you're using to query the database and send back the response.

Comment: @robertklep I have added the bit of code to explain the issue.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to stream if you need to send back a complex object. In that case, you may have to limit the amount of data that you're sending back (and use paging, perhaps).