# CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - rails webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, webpack-dev-server

I did some research to fix the JS heap size issue - the answer is to set the max_old_space_size

Eg: [FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)
However, `./bin/webpack-dev-server --max_old_space_size=4096` is not an option

Anyone else ran into the same issue? How did you fix it?

My package.json does not have scripts as suggested in some other posts.

Our setup is somewhat similar to this - https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md

Comment: While I am waiting for a better solution using this as a mid-term fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379336

Comment: Do you really need `>4 GB` heap size for your application?

Comment: The default is 512 for node applications and that's what is failing. 4096 was just an example I used. I need > 512 for sure because I run into JS heap out of memory error when I try to run my app. I currently don't know of a way to changing max_old_space_size.