# NPM Getting Aborted Error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new in nodejs i have installed nodejs successfully, when i init the npm  i am getting aborted error.

I have a lot of memory means 32GB RAM and 1TB HD.

Only npm -v command working rest all command not working with npm.

Please see the below error and help me.

```
[xyz@server node]$ npm init

<--- Last few GCs --->

[13396:0x4389aa0]      126 ms: Scavenge 6.3 (10.8) -> 5.2 (11.8) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure
[13396:0x4389aa0]      168 ms: Scavenge 7.7 (12.3) -> 6.7 (12.8) MB, 2.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure
[13396:0x4389aa0]      215 ms: Scavenge 8.5 (12.8) -> 7.6 (16.8) MB, 12.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x89a0c0 node::Abort() [npm]
 2: 0x89a10c  [npm]
 3: 0xa879be v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm]
 4: 0xa87bd8 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm]
 5: 0xe753e2  [npm]
 6: 0xea6376 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [npm]
 7: 0xea69d2 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [npm]
 8: 0xe808b1 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [npm]
 9: 0xe80fb1 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm]
10: 0xe81c74 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm]
11: 0xe845a5 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm]
12: 0xe4d3b8 v8::internal::Factory::NewFeedbackVector(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [npm]
13: 0xe29453 v8::internal::FeedbackVector::New(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>)[npm]
14: 0xf77319 v8::internal::JSFunction::EnsureFeedbackVector(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>) [npm]
15: 0xd9e60a v8::internal::Compiler::Compile(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ClearExceptionFlag) [npm]
16: 0x10b9822 v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]
17: 0x3f6b33a041bd
Aborted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

Comment: I have tried that solution that is not working with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to overcome the `FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` error is to increase the memory allocation, for which we need to set the the `max_old_space_size` variable value accordingly,

For e.g,

`node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js` => This will allocate 1GB memory.

Hence try increasing it like,

`node --max_old_space_size=2048` and once done execute your `npm init` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for Solution but it is not working. I am getting same error.

Comment: @eharajhusain Probably you can increase the current `2048` value, or else better try this npm package =>  [increase-memory-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit)

Comment: i used this but npm command is not working got same error. Main problem with npm command it is not working whatever i run with npm got same error.

Comment: Ah.. I can understand the issue now.

Comment: @eharajhusain Goto command prompt, type `node` hit enter then execute `process.memoryUsage()` and post what you receive there.

Comment: received =>rss: 19185664,
  heapTotal: 9732096,
  heapUsed: 4922256,
  external: 8760

Comment: hey, @David please reply

Comment: Okay, Can you try allocating more memory, Use this command => `node --max-old-space-size=1024000`

Comment: I used and after used we got      rss: 18857984,
  heapTotal: 9732096,
  heapUsed: 4559272,
  external: 8800

Comment: Thank you so much @David. Now it is working perfect. will it create problem again ?

Comment: Great!. I hope it won't occur again. Feel free mark it answered then! ;-)

Comment: Hey @David Again this problem has come and i got only aborted message after run NPM command i have tried to increase max-old-space-size but it's not working. Plz help me

Comment: @eharajhusain Looks very strange!. :( Let me try few workarounds and get back.

Comment: Hi @David Thanks a lot for response. the problem with cpanel user when i switch user from root by using SU command it's working perfect but when login form user directly than i got aborted error.