# What can cause ExpressJS to timeout all requests?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, http

I have an ExpressJS app running on EC2 in a docker container which suddenly stopped responding to any requests after 6 days of normal operation with similar requests.  The CPU and network traffic looked normal, but I don't have memory metrics because AWS doesn't automatically collect those.

Once I restarted the container, it resumed responding to requests as normal.

**Under what circumstances would an Express app stop responding to requests?**

Possible causes I can think of:

- Code running stuck in an infinite loop (but this would max out the CPU)
- Memory full

What else could cause this?

Comment: What is the tier plan of your EC2 instance? I hope it won't be `t2.micro`

Comment: For second reason, you may refer to this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852018/6536335

Comment: It can be a couple of things. If the application doesn't have proper error handling and  something can break it, in that case if the automatic restart is not set up, it won't restart.

Comment: Forgetting to call `next()` in a middleware (seen this enough times in the wild) and forgetting to either call `next()` or `res.send()` in a controller (very easy to do in complicated if/else structure or promise chain or callback nesting)

Comment: @AliD,. It's a beefy instance

Comment: @SándorBakos, It is set up to automatically restart, the service hadn't crashed, it just wasn't returning responses.

Comment: @slebetman, It's been functioning as expected for 6 days, handling all the same requests, and when I restarted it, it returned to normal operation - so it couldn't be one of those.

Comment: If you want to monitor memory usage, you can set up manually, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html. And if you have logging in the application you can take a look at them in the aws cloudwatch service

Comment: @SándorBakos, thank you, that is my next step

Comment: The same happens with me multiple times now, I couldn't figure out what causes the problem, the request will be pending until you restart the server. One thing I could think of is that the application was waiting for database to respond.