# Npm module "csv-to-array" does not read entire CSV file given as input

Tags: javascript, npm, csvtoarray

I am trying to read CSV file in JavaScript using npm module `csv-to-array` into an array.
I expect the *rows_in_csv* array to hold all rows (count > 1000) of CSV.
But it holds data for only first 507 rows. This is the issue.

```
let fs = require('fs');
let cwd = __dirname;
let file_path = cwd.concat("/farsi_localization_data.csv");

require("csv-to-array")({
  file: file_path,
  columns: ["Complete key", "", "English Value", "Hindi Value"]
}, function (err, rows_in_csv) {
  let row_count = rows_in_csv.length;

  console.log(`number of rows in CSV is ${row_count}`);
});
```

Please tell why this would be happening.

Comment: please give a sample file u are trying

Comment: Is there anything notably different about row #507 in the `.csv` file?

Comment: @PRAJINPRAKASH stackoverflow does not allow file upload. please check this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VjdYuTuCN6VEdQoQZQl9hHP0oJSijMeQFn9isxXZFHg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Row no. 507 seems to be the first row that has a cell with line break in it.

Comment: @NishantKumar yes please remove newlines from the file on line 507 and 508.
then you may get an error `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` just do [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

Comment: yes. i removed newlines. after that got the above error! now trying to fix that.. @PRAJINPRAKASH

Comment: @NishantKumar Best way is do split csv into small files. Try  node --max-old-space-size=4076 filename.js

Comment: hmm "node --max-old-space-size=4076 update-farsi-json-file.js" did not work. finally i wrote ruby script to do this job :)

Comment: splitting the CSV file into small files may also solve the issue. but the fact that we are unable to read a CSV with 2000 rows only using above code is bad!